# How to resolve 'No such element exception'?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, page-objects, exception

I am getting below error even though I was using correct identifier.

```
No such element exception: Unable to locate element:
{"method":"id","selector":"input_001"}
```

HTML Code:

```
<input type="text" name="UserName" class="md-input" id="input_001">
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried with @FindBy(name="UserName") as well, but it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: try xpath by.xpath(//input(@class='md-input'))[contains(text(),'UserName')]

Comment: your element is within the iFrame, so first try to switch that particular iframe and then try to locate that element.

Answer (score 1):

You have element inside the `iframe`. So in Selenium, to work with element which is in embedded resource such as frame, you need to first switch into respective `iframe` and then perform the actions.

There are following ways to switch into frame :

1. Switch to the frame by index :

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame(0);
   ```
2. Switch to the frame by Name or ID attributes :

   e.g. `<frame src="http://52.24.63.155/lifepal/AdminPanel" name="adminPanel" id="some_id">`

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame("adminPanel");
   driver.switchTo().frame("some_id");
   ```
3. Switch to the frame by Web Element

   ```
   WebElement frame = driver.findElement(By.locator);

   driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
   ```
4. You can use ExplicitWait as well :

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'http://52.24.63.155/lifepal/AdminPanel')]")));
   ```

And then perform the action. In Page Factory fashion your element would be :

```
@FindBy(id="input_001")
private WebElement username;

public WebElement getUsername(){
    return username;
}

public void sendUsername(String uname){
    getUsername().sendKeys(uname);
}
```

Comment: Hi @NarendraR sorry i could not understand your statements.

Comment: Pleaes let me know where should I include SwithTo Statement, i.e. in Page Class or Test Case class?

Comment: @DVadlamoodi, Test Case class

Comment: Thank you as you noticed, frame doesn't have any name or id.

Comment: `new WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'http://52.24.63.155/lifepal/AdminPanel')]")));`  use this one, it will automatically find the frame and switch in. (replace the frame `src` attribute properly)  and let me know further

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to select it by using :

```
Public  Username By = By.id(“ input-001”);
```

Comment: Thank you! but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

This webelement is inside an Iframe. So switch into the Iframe first try the below code

```
@FindBy(id="input_001")
private WebElement Input_001;
```

Then in the code Page Factory selenium is written as

```
public void userLogin(String Input){
Input_001.sendKeys(Input)
}
```

Comment: Hi @Prasanna
Can you please let me know where i should write code for Switch to Frame? is it in Page Class or Test Case class file? Sorry, i am very basic learner of Selenium

Comment: Hi @Vadlamoodi include the switchto statements before this line. @FindBy(id="input_001")

Comment: This is Page Class
public class Login {
 
 
 @FindBy(how=How.NAME, using="UserName")
 private WebElement user;
 
 @FindBy(name="password")
 private WebElement pwd;
 
 @FindBy(name="signin")
 private WebElement submit;
 
 public Login (WebDriver driver) {
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
 }
 public void applicationLogin() {
  
  user.sendKeys("xxxxx");
  pwd.sendKeys("xxxxx");
  submit.click();
 }

I don't thik it accepts driver statement below webelement declaration